# PyGTK set icon of window with stock image

Tags: python, gtk, icons, pygtk, gdkpixbuf

I feel like this should be pretty simple, but I guess I am missing something.

So I want to set the icon of a window with one of the stock images.  I have tried:

```
windowIcon = gtk.image_new_form_stock(gtk.STOCK_DIALOG_AUTHENTICATION, gtk.ICON_SIZE_MENU)
window.set_icon(windowIcon.get_pixbuf())
```

Python then complains that:

> File "./sample.py", line 44, in **init** 
>   window.set_icon(windowIcon.get_pixbuf()) 
>   ValueError: image should be a GdkPixbuf or empty

I try to convert the gtkImage to a GdkPixbuf because when I didn't python complained that

> TypeError: icon should be a GdkPixbuf or None

In the pygtk documentation it says:

> If the storage type of the image is not either gtk.IMAGE_EMPTY or gtk.IMAGE_PIXBUF the ValueError exception will be raised.

So I guessing that storage type of the stock image is wrong.  The question is how to I get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the .render_icon() method on any GtkWidget to provide a stock item as the icon.

```
windowicon = window.render_icon(gtk.STOCK_DIALOG_AUTHENTICATION, gtk.ICON_SIZE_MENU)
window.set_icon(windowicon)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would you know how I would set a custom icon from the file system?

Answer (score 2):

The `render_icon()` method works as given above. Your code was having problems, because the `get_pixbuf()` method was returning `None`. This is because the image was not created from a `pixbuf`, and for some reason, it won't convert it. Another way of getting a `pixbuf` from an image is to use the `gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_image()` function.